# calling java function from xslt not working

Tags: java, eclipse, xalan

I know that there are so many responses about it, but I'he tried with many of them with no success, so, here am I:

I have an XSL and I'm calling to a java method inside. After a couple of attempts (cannot find mypackage.MyClass) I'm getting 'Instance method new needs one object as a first parameter' (roughly translated, I'm sorry).
BUT MyClass doesn't have a Constructor defined, not even a default constructor. I tried by defining a void constructor, but with no effect.

When I try to call to any function, I get a NullPointerException, cause my instance variable is null. If I take my method and add as static, I get 'Instance method MyMethod needs one object as a first parameter'.

AND, the best. If I use any default java class (java.util.Date, java.lang.XXXX, and so on), my tests works!

I'm going crazy...

Here is my last test.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/java.util.Date"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    xmlns:test="mypackage.MyClass"
    exclude-result-prefixes="date java test">

  <xsl:template match="/">

   <!-- WORKING EXAMPLE -->
   <xsl:variable name="dateObject"
     select="date:new(java_lang:Math.max(1027695561000,1038695561000))"/>
   Date of object: <xsl:value-of select="$dateObject"/>
   Time of object: <xsl:value-of select="date:getTime($dateObject)"/>

  <!-- ERRORS... -->
  <xsl:variable name="testObject1" select="test:new()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="result" select="test:myMethod($testObject1)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="testObject2" select="test:go()"/>


  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my class:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyClass{

    public String myMethod(){
        return "YESSSS!!!";
    }

    public static String go(){
        return "GOOOO!!!";
    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse Luna for debugging purposes and Xalan 2.7.1.
My class is under {project}/src/dsig folder and my xsl is under {project}/resources folder.

I've tested with xalan:extension tag, with abbreviate (as in the official xalan page) and many examples (including some taken from this forum) and all it's the same...

Can you give me a hand?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards.

Tistklehoff

Comment: `xmlns:test="java:mypackage.MyClass"`?

Comment: `xmlns:test="mypackage.MyClass"` should probably be `xmlns:test="xalan://mypackage.MyClass"` but apart from that what you have here should work already.

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

With xmlns:test="java:mypackage.MyClass", both methods (instance and static) return: 'Instance method new/go requires an instance object as first argument'.
By adding xmlns:xalan="http:// xml.apache.org/xalan" and xmlns:test="xalan://mypackage.MyClass" have the same result.

Any other ideas?

Kind Regards.